# Algorithm for reducing sequence into smaller sequence (for specific fn)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, average

I have a sequence of $(X,Y)$ pairs: $(X_0,Y_0),\ldots(X_N,Y_N)$

I add a new pair to the sequence at every time step, $t$

At some time in the distant future, $t_n$, I want to use a function to reduce the sequence into a number.

The function takes the sequence of pairs and an input $Z$:
$$
f(Z) = \left(\frac{1}{X_0}-\frac{1}{Z}\right)\cdot Y_0 + \left(\frac{1}{X_1}-\frac{1}{Z}\right)\cdot Y_1 + \ldots + \left(\frac{1}{X_N}-\frac{1}{Z}\right)\cdot Y_N
$$
My problem:

I don't want to store every pair of these sequences. This would require too much space.
I want to reduce the sequence into some kind of incremental representation that will allow me to

- Store much fewer pairs
- Compute $f(Z)$ without any loss of precision, at any time

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe better on [csSE](https://cs.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Nice suggestion, I will post it  over there too. Please remove from here if it does not fit.

Comment: You can simplify that function by expanding the multiplications, gathering together all the terms with a $Z$ as one sum, and all the terms without a $Z$ as another sum. Those two sums are then the only things you need to keep track of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you have is this:
$$f(Z) = \left(\frac{1}{X_0}-\frac{1}{Z}\right)Y_0 + \left(\frac{1}{X_1}-\frac{1}{Z}\right)Y_1 + \ldots + \left(\frac{1}{X_N}-\frac{1}{Z}\right)Y_N$$

Expand the multiplications:
$$f(Z) = \frac{Y_0}{X_0}-\frac{Y_0}{Z} + \frac{Y_1}{X_1}-\frac{Y_1}{Z} + \ldots + \frac{Y_N}{X_N}-\frac{Y_N}{Z}$$

Rearrange:
$$f(Z) = \left(\frac{Y_0}{X_0}+ \frac{Y_1}{X_1} + \ldots + \frac{Y_N}{X_N} \right) - \left( \frac{Y_0}{Z} + \frac{Y_1}{Z} + \ldots + \frac{Y_N}{Z}\right)$$

So we get:
$$f(Z) = S - \frac{T}{Z}$$
where
$$S = \frac{Y_0}{X_0}+ \frac{Y_1}{X_1} + \ldots + \frac{Y_N}{X_N}$$
and
$$T = Y_0 + Y_1 + \ldots + Y_N$$
Those $S$ and $T$ are easy to update when you get an additional pair.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted! So if I was to keep the same representation, I would just add two extra elements to each pair, S and T? So we get <X,Y,S,T> where S and T are the sums that you defined up to that specific pair?

Comment: @Soggiorno I don't understand what you are asking. You should only store $S$ and $T$. If you receive a new pair $(X_{N+1},Y_{N+1})$ you update $S$ and $T$ by adding $Y_{N+1}/X_{N+1}$ to $S$ and $Y_{N+1}$ to $T$, and then use those new values of $S$ and $T$ in the function.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up! And if you have two pairs of S,T, you just turn them into one by adding S_0 with S_1 and T_0 with T_1?

Comment: If you have two of these functions $f_1$ and $f_2$, each based on their own separate set of data pairs, then you can combine them into one function $f_3$ based on the combined set of pairs by adding them: $S_3=S_1+S_2$ and $T_3=T_1+T_2$.

Comment: Thank you! You have been a great help.